# Boolean Logic in Linear Interpolation

Tags: image-processing, boolean-logic, hex

http://tech-algorithm.com/articles/linear-interpolation/

This is the code.

In the code given on this page, I couldn't understand what does this

```
         return 0xff000000 | // alpha
                ((Yr << 16) & 0xff0000) |
                ((Yg << 8) & 0xff00) |
                (Yb & 0xff) ;
```

do. To be more specific, I don't know what is this `(Yr << 16)`. Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple function to convert an RGB triplet (three unsigned 8-bit values) into an unsigned 32-bit ARGB value.

The `<<` operator shifts the binary digits of an integer to the left by the specified number of places. So, for example, if `Yr`=100, `Yg`=150 and `Yb`=200 then you would end up with the 32-bit number 0xFF6496C8, where the RGB information is stored as follows:

```
 ---- alpha ----  ----- Yr ------  ----- Yg ------  ----- Yb ------
[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1][0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0][1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0][1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 alpha=255=0xFF   Yr=0x64=100      Yg=0x96=150      Yb=0xC8=200
```

The alpha value (255) presumably corresponds to 100% opacity.

In case you were wondering, the `&` operator is a logical AND operator that masks out the unwanted bits. In the code you linked to, it's doesn't appear to be necessary at all since the values Yr, Yg and Yb are already in the range from 0 to 255.

However, it is useful when extracting RGB values from a 32-bit ARGB integer, e.g.:

```
alpha = (ARGB >> 24) & 0xff;
Yr = (ARGB >> 16) & 0xff;
Yg = (ARGB >> 8) & 0xff;
Yb = ARGB & 0xff;
```